# When setAlwaysOnTop doesn't work, how to track and switch to child windows?

Tags: java, swing, window, awt

I have a Java application - it imports both `AWT` and `Swing` - which fills the entire screen without "decoration," so there's no minimizing it. At some point it needs to display a help file to a user. It should block until the user closes the window. So, here's the code:

```
fileview dlg = new fileview(this, title, filename, "");
dlg.setModal(true); //Makes it UI blocking!
dlg.setResizable(false);
dlg.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
dlg.setVisible(true);
```

`fileview` extends `JDialog`, so it becomes an independent window, except that it closes when the parent does.

Unfortunately, I've found that on some platforms it honors `setAlwaysOnTop(true)` and sometimes it doesn't. When not working, if the user "clicks away" the input focus shifts back to the parent but because of `setModal(true)`, it's hung.

Also unfortunately, I've wasted A WEEK on this, and I'm under a huge time crunch to get this working and have a lot more work to do, so **I've given up wasting my time trying to figure out WHY `setAlwaysOnTop` isn't working.** (I read, just as I'm giving up, that mixing `AWT` and `Swing` may have something to do with this, but since `Swing` is built on top of `AWT`, IDK what to think.)

**Instead, I would like to NOT `setModal` and just track the child that's created and then switch input focus back to it when the time is appropriate, rather than creating a lot of lost children.**

SO, I tried saving the `fileview`, and I can apply methods to it, but I don't know which one to call to make it appear over the top of the current window and accept input focus. I've tried `.setVisible(true)` and `.setAlwaysOnTop(true)` (in hopes somehow that makes it true even for a moment!) to no avail. ...I looked through all the inherited classes I could think of that might have the right method,but didn't see it; **what method(s) do I apply?**

Comment: `At some point it needs to display a help file to a user. It should block until the user closes the window.` - use a modal JDialog and specify the frame as the parent. End of story. There is no need to worry about always on top. Class names should start with an upper case character.

Comment: @camickr Except that that's not working. Now what? And what on earth are you talking about "class names should"? You're free to set your own naming standards.

Comment: Have you tried to use a JWindow instead of JDialog? (Just throwing an idea. JWindow might behave differently)

Comment: `Except that that's not working.` - post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem. `You're free to set your own naming standards.` - when you ask for help on a forum you follow the standards of the community. The forum highlight posted code based of Java naming standards to make the code easier to read for everybody.

Comment: @GeorgeZougianos No, George, I haven't yet, and while I REALLY WANT an answer to the question asked above, camickr's comment got me thinking and I found why the JDialog modality wasn't working: Somehow the super(parent_frame) was inadvertently deleted and on some platforms it assumes the parent correctly and on others it does not! So, that's something...

Comment: @camickr 'when you ask for help on a forum you follow the standards of the community. The forum highlight posted code based of Java naming standards to make the code easier to read for everybody.' ...It's trivial to prove that at least some of the "standards" actually make work harder for everybody. The reality is, it's just what you're used to. But this is not a place to have that discussion.  And thanks for your tip-off about the parent, that was a good clue. Now, what about bringing forth an extant frame to the fore?

Comment: `some of the "standards"  - actually make work harder ` It is not harder to upper case the words of a class name for follow conventions. Using proper case makes it easier to read. All the classes in the JDK follow this convention. `it's just what you're used to` - it is what everybody in the forum is used to. Again the highlighting in the forum is based on these conventions. If you don't want to make it easier for us to help you, then good luck. `what about bringing forth an extant frame to the fore?` - no ideas what you are asking and I still don't see your [mcve].